# How to share state between Akka actors?

Tags: scala, akka, mutable

I have a `BalanceSheetActor` defined as follows:

```
class BalanceSheetActor extends Actor {

  val tradables = mutable.Set[Contract]

}
```

and I have some simple `DepositContract` defined as follows:

```
case class DepositContract(faceValue: Double)
```

Each contract in my model is an asset for one `BalanceSheetActor` and a liability for another `BalanceSheetActor` and thus the state of any `Contract` will be shared between actors (i.e., each contract will be a member of at least two sets of `tradables`).

Suppose that I want to increment the `faceValue` of the `DepositContract` by some `amount`.  I would either need to...

1. remove the old contract from both sets of `tradables` and replace it with a new `DepositContract(faceValue + amount)`.
2. model each `Contract` as an `akka.Agent`.
3. model each `Contract` as an `akka.Actor` (and thus encapsulating the state).

Option 1 seems needlessly complicated (additionally contracts are highly likely to get out of sync), option 2 seems OK but I will need to create on the order of millions of contract agents and am concerned about memory usage. I have similar concerns for option 3 as well. I have no idea if these memory usage concerns are well founded. Thoughts?

I am hoping that there is an option 4 that this Scala/Akka noob has not thought of...

Comment: Sharing state between [actors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) goes exactly in the opposite way of the actor's model philosophy

Comment: Agreed. However, in this case, shared state is a fundamental property of the system I am trying to model.

Comment: Are you sure actors are the appropriate place for the state of this kind? It seems to me that a system supporting ACID transactions (like a relational database) might be better suited for handling the storage of a financial data. The actors can still be used for the processing of transactions.

Comment: I am not storing financial data, but am rather building a large-scale multi-agent system/agent-based model of financial markets.

Comment: Why would option 1 necessarily be complicated?  Use a Map[ContractId,Contract], and simply replace the map entry when a contract is modified.

Comment: Nice idea @JimN. But I would need to send a message to at least two actors every time any change was made to any contract in order to implement this.  This feels a bit wasteful...but then again maybe it would be more efficient relative to options 2 and 3.

Comment: @JimN I would also be concerned about contracts getting out of sync with one another. Now that I think about it, this is sure to happen under option 1!

Comment: And you are planning to deploy this system in a single node? or you are planning to go distributed? In both cases I don't see the problem with option 1, although in the latter case you would probably need to embrace eventual consistency and create some saga for the updates. If eventual consistency is not enough for you, then @GregorRayman's comment sounds right. Also, if you go distributed, using option 3 with cluster sharding looks good to me.

Comment: How about having a single actor which acts as recording agency.  This actor is the definitive source for all contracts.  Whenever a change must be made to a contract, it must be made through this actor.  Other actors can "listen" for changes by sending a message to this actor requesting to receive updates.

Comment: @kaktusito I do plan on going distributed at some point. Unfortunately eventual consistency is not an option as I would worry that it would introduce artifacts into the simulation.  Both option 2 and 3 do not issues with consistency (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how you solved this in the end. I'm trying to model a similar behaviour and wanted to know if there was a better way than going to a db if the app is distributed